# python vk_api возникла проблема

Tags: python

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой что бот вк пропускает некоторые elif при ответе. То есть на комманду - привет он отвечает, на hzchto отвечает, а вот на Тест1 и Help1 нет, с чем это может быть связанно? Работает рандомно, пробовал разные комманды вписывать, некоторые просто пропускает и сразу переходит к else...

```
    if request.lower() == "привет":
        write_msg(event.user_id, "Здравствуйте, чем я могу вам помочь? Чтобы узнать что я могу напишите - помощь")
    elif request.lower() == "hzchto":
        write_msg(event.user_id, "Список того что я могу")
    elif request.lower() == "Тест1":
        write_msg(event.user_id, "1121")
    elif request.lower() == "Help1":
        write_msg(event.user_id, "1121")
    else:
        write_msg(event.user_id, "Не поняла вашего ответа...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переведи строки запроса примером на:

```
 if request.upper() == "ПРИВЕТ":
```

и так далее

Comment: Вроде работает, спасибо)